# Why does [[:alpha:]] in Notepad++ also match Chinese words?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Why does the regex expression [[:alpha:]] also match Chinese words in Notepad++? For example, ，中文

According to the documentation of Notepad++

> alpha : ASCII letters

Chinese words are not ASCII letters, so why does the regex expression match them?

Comment: Where are you using that code that it doesn't find `中文`? Might need the `u` modifier. https://regex101.com/r/zT4mO1/1

Comment: @chris85 Oh, so it is designed to match Chinese words? But I thought [[:alpha:]] only matches ASCII letters. Are Chinese words ASCII letters??

Comment: Take a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html. If you only have support for ascii it will be ascii only.

Comment: @chris85 I don't understand what you mean. In the link you provide, there is g and u modifier , so that [[:alpha:]] matches Chinese word. But the problem is I don't want to [[:alpha:]] to match Chinese word, and it should not match Chinese word, because I didn't add g or u modifier in Notepad++

Comment: On [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311935/are-text-editor-regex-questions-off-topic?cb=1) - unusual voting patterns may have been because of this.

Comment: @penne12 I am surprised at such a hot debate caused by my question : )

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `[:alpha:]` class normally matches alphabetic characters.  This would be much more than ASCII letters, depending on the encoding you are using.

While the [Notepad++ documentation](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions) does state "ASCII letters", it also indicates that regexes are implemented using the [Boost C++ Regex library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html).  Documentation confirms that `[:alpha:]` [has the standard, broader meaning in this library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/character_classes/std_char_clases.html).

This appears to be just a mistake in the Notepad++ documentation.

If you need to match ASCII letters, I would use something like `[a-zA-Z]` as a starting point.

Comment: So Chinese words are alphabetic Character? I must say this extension is not useful at all

Comment: Just because it isn't *your* alphabet, doesn't mean it isn't part of an alphabet!

Comment: @Troyseph While I agree with you, technically the Chinese language does not have an alphabet; it is a logographic writing system with a supplementary list of phonetic elements with determinatives. =P

Comment: @That1Guy Good point. I guess that alpha in this context is simply a way of filtering out numerical and punctuation characters.

Comment: @Troyseph I definitely agree with That1Guy. Because I am Chinese, to me, there is a huge difference between Chinese characters and English letters. I think it is just useless to put them in the same group, because one thing we often do is to add space between Chinese and English letters to differentiates them clearly. For numerical and punctuation, we already have `\d` and `[:punct :]` to use, so your point is not that strong to me.

Comment: @user15964, while I see there is a big difference between Chinese characters and alphabetic characters, to me it seems useful to have a class that matches letters/words/text in any language.  "alpha" might not be a very good name for this, but I'm not sure there is a better alternative.

Comment: @dan1111 it is enough to me if `alpha` only match English letter : )

Comment: @user15964, yeah, but what about everyone else's requirements? :)

Comment: @user15964 [Check out this page on 'posixbrackets' by regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) It gives you everything you need to know and more! Also it would be weird to have `[:digit:]` `[:punct:]` and not `[:alpha:]`...